# Why would a “hosts” file prevent a VPN from forwarding a port?

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding, hosts-file

I would like to maintain my hosts block list while being able to use my VPNs forwarded port service, but have a conflict.

1. I connect to a VPN server that port forwards, and my HOSTS file has only the default entries:

   ```
   127.0.0.1    localhost
   255.255.255.255  broadcasthost
   ::1             localhost 
   fe80::1%lo0  localhost
   ```

   I see that it has indeed forwarded a port. Success.
2. I connect to a VPN server that port forwards, but I have added a list of hostnames to block in my HOSTS file. Eg. `0.0.0.0 fr.a2dfp.net`. These are from the popular [MVPS HOSTS file](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm) for blocking adware, etc. The HOSTS file has 9942 lines and is 263 KB.

Now I can connect to the VPN but the server consistently fails to forward a port. No matter which server I connect to that provides port forwarding — they fail to do so. Removing all of the added hostnames from the HOSTS file resolves this.

I have converted all of the hostnames in the block list to IP addresses to check if any of them are a PIA address but none are.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do nslookup "$line" | grep ^Name -A1 | awk '{print $2}'; done <./HOSTS1.txt >/Users/john/Desktop/HostIP.txt
```

I guess the question is what would cause this issue where I can connect to the VPN but they are unable to forward a port due to my HOSTS file. How do I determine which hostname entry is causing this conflict?

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but I expect this was downvoted because the hosts file is unrelated to port forwarding.  The solution may be to divide an conquer - ie try half the hosts file, if that works, add another half the remainder and so on, if it fails, remove lines until it works.  Then work out which line(s) are causing the issue and diagnose the underlying issue.

Comment: Why is port forwarding involved? Is your VPN server behind a NAT? So your VPN client doesn't actually get a publicly-routed IP address inside the VPN tunnel?

Comment: @davidgo I didn't know it was downvoted out of spite. Seems odd to downvote a question like this since I am stating that the behavior was confounding in the beginning. Thus after taking steps to reproduce the behavior I got on StackExchange to see if someone could explain it. In advance of posting I did remove all and add parts of the list back in to try and narrow it down, but found nothing. I am wondering if my DNS cache was corrupted? I really don't know what would cause this on my side other than the VPN's app having some conflict with files on my system.